# I use a dynamic compiler in Angular, but it only works in the View Engine, but view engine is deprecated

Tags: angular, npm, dynamic, build, compilation

I get this info:

```
Project is attempting to disable the Ivy compiler. Angular versions 12 and higher do not support the deprecated View Engine compiler for applications. The Ivy compiler will be used to build this project. 
For additional information or if the build fails, please see https://angular.io/guide/ivy
```

So my NPM package is only works with view engine because dynamic compilation is not working with Ivy as it is AOT.

So what can I do to create for an Ivy build with using dynamic compilation?

This is the NPM package:
https://github.com/patrikx3/angular-compile

Answer (score 0):

never mind, my package it works with Ivy as well. Closing.